# Why is $rM$ a submodule?

Tags: abstract-algebra, modules

Let $R$ be a ring and $M$ be a $R$-module. In Example 5.10 of [Algebra: Chapter 0](http://www.mimuw.edu.pl/~jarekw/pdf/Algebra0TextboookAluffi.pdf) that for $r\in R$, \begin{equation}
rM=\{r\cdot m:m\in M\}
\end{equation} is a submodule of $M$.

I have no problem showing that this is a subgroup of $M$, but why is it closed under the actions of $R$? That is, given $m\in M$ and $s\in R$, how can we find $n\in M$ such that \begin{equation}
s\cdot (r\cdot m)=r\cdot n.
\end{equation}

Thanks!

Comment: $A$ is not commutative?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is an explicit counterexample when $R$ is not commutative:

Let $R=k\langle x,y\rangle$, the free associative $k$-algebra on the indeterminates $x$ and $y$. We can of course consider the left $R$-module $M=R$. However, the subset $xM$ is not a left submodule of $M$, because $yx$ cannot be written as $xr$ for any $r\in R$.

Comment: Thanks! So this is a typo in the book. I will send the author an email.

Answer (score 1):

Usually while dealing with modules Ring $R$ will be commutative with unity , if that is the case, $ s.(r.m) = r.(s.m)$ and as $M$ is module $ s.m \in M,$ so $s.m = n$ for some $n\in M$
If the ring is not commutative, usually it need not be a sub module.